# Setting priority when creating processes with batch file

Tags: c#, batch-file

In my c# program I generate a batch file and run it with cmd.
The batch file in turn creates more processes (I'll call them "child processes").
I wish for the child processes to have the same priority as the batch file. It works fine when batch's priority is <= NORMAL, but if it is higher, the child processes' priority is just NORMAL. I don't want use the `START` command as I need to wait for a child process finish before moving on.

Comment: http://www.itworld.com/nls_windows_lowpriority060814

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) command and use the /wait option.

```
/wait : Starts an application and waits for it to end.
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/b20d0b58-221f-4341-a425-66bd2d717163/) you can find good explanation about process priorities.

Probably you parent process should have at least the same process priority, not lower that you will set.

Comment: Parent process is a cmd that is running my batch file. I can easily affect it's priority, but nut it's child processes. I need to set priority to the child processes

Comment: Probably the only way is to set priority in your batch file because you can't affect on this from the code.

Comment: Well, it is exactly my question. How to create a process with specifyed priority with batch file and wait for this process to terminate (before executing the next command in batch)?

Comment: Probably using `start /high '<command>` command from command line. [Here](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) is details